# Sorting in Isotope: Why Does My Masonry Layout Disappear?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've implemented jQuery Isotope in a site I'm building, and I've run into an odd problem. The initial masonry layout works fine. I have a randomize button that calls the 'shuffle' function, and it does exactly what you would expect it to do.

The button that *doesn't* work is the one that implements a sort by image titles. The sort itself works as it should, meaning that the items end up in proper order, *but* the masonry layout breaks, and all the images end up in a single row down the left side of the container.

Below are: my initial Isotope load function, my working 'shuffle' function, and my broken 'sortBy' function.

```
var $container = jQuery('#isotopegallery');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.photo',
        masonry: {
            coumnWidth: 270,
            gutterWidth: 10
        }
    });
});

jQuery('#randomize').click(function(){
    $container.isotope( 'shuffle' );
});

//Isotope sort data
$container.isotope({
  getSortData : {
    title : function ( $elem ) {
      return $elem.find('.title').text();
    }
  }
});

jQuery('#sortByTitle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope({ sortBy : 'title'});    
});
```

**EDIT:** I've built a jsFiddle with a simplified version of what I'm doing, and, of course, it works perfectly fine there. I'm hunting through to see what's different in my actual project. jsFiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXNZH/

Comment: You got a jsfiddle or jsbin to demonstrate the problem online with code?

Comment: I've edited the post to add one, but as I note, it actually works there, so it doesn't help me. I'm looking to see if there's some kind of conflict cropping up.

Comment: Well, if the fiddle works, then the issue is indeed hard to pinpoint. By the way, you can add resources in jsfiddles under Manage Resources on the left and paste http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js in there. That makes your fiddle more manageable and faster. No need to paste tons of minified code in the js window.

Comment: If your code above is a cut & paste you may want to change the spelling of the masonry setting from coumnWidth to columnWidth!